# simulated clock java homework

Tags: java, clock

The class is called operating systems and I have to make a simulated clock that reads information at certain time and does something with it but I am only asking about the clock part here. Right now, I have 4 buttons which are <kbd>run</kbd>, <kbd>tick</kbd>, <kbd>read</kbd>, and <kbd>show status</kbd>. I have an input, an output, and a timer text field. I have a `clockstarter` class that starts the clock when the program starts and writes it in the console. I'm supposed to have two threads so that while that is happening I can click "run" and the timer textfield starts continuously counting or if run is not clicked, I can manually add time with tick. I need help getting it to show in the text field.

```
public class ClockStarter implements Runnable {

private Thread thread;
private int currentTime;
private javax.swing.JTextField time;
public ClockStarter(javax.swing.JTextField t){
    System.out.println("Clock Starter Constructor");
    currentTime = -1;
   time = t;
   thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
public void run(){
    while(true){

        incrementTime();
        System.out.println("Clock Starter Current Time ");
        time = ("" + getCurrentTime());// I need to fix this line
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
public void incrementTime(){
    currentTime++;
}
public int getCurrentTime(){
    return currentTime;
}
}
```

Comment: If there's something else you need to know just ask, the how to thing said try to only give needed information so I didn't want to put too much in. I'm new on here obviously.

Comment: when you set it on text field the text is updated, the component knows how to redraw itself, but if you create other textbox you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use `Thread.sleep()` as it will freeze your Swing application.

Instead you should use a `javax.swing.Timer`.

See the Java tutorial [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.

Please read the Swing tutorial [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html):

> A text field is a basic text control that enables the user to type a small amount of text. When the user indicates that text entry is complete (usually by pressing Enter), the text field fires an action event. If you need to obtain more than one line of input from the user, use a text area.

Example Code

```
/* TextDemo.java requires no other files. */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    protected JTextField textField;
    protected JTextArea textArea;
    private final static String newline = "\n";

    public TextDemo() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        //Add Components to this panel.
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(textField, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        add(scrollPane, c);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = textField.getText();
        textArea.append(text + newline);
        textField.selectAll();

        //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
        //was a selection in the text area.
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new TextDemo());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```